# Join teams in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

I have two tables: I want to display the teams that play against each other and their score.

[image]

I tried this:

```
SELECT Wedstrijd.Team1, Wedstrijd.Team2, Wedstrijd.ScoreTeam1, Wedstrijd.ScoreTeam2
FROM Wedstrijd
JOIN Team ON idTeam = idWedstrijd
```

Outcome:

```
'1', '2', '1', '4'
'3', '4', '3', '1'
```

Now i need the names that come with the ID.

- Naam = Name
- Stad = City

Comment: though I'm not clear of your issue, try this `SELECT w.Team1, w.Team2, w.ScoreTeam1, w.ScoreTeam2, t.Naam FROM Wedstrijd w JOIN Team t ON t.idTeam = w.idWedstrijd`

Comment: Team 1 play against Team 2

Comment: Team 3 play against Team 4

Comment: I want to display both teams, the last two numbers are the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    W.Team1, t1.Naam, t1.Stad,  
    W.Team2, t2.Naam, t2.Stad, 
    W.ScoreTeam1, w.ScoreTeam2
FROM Wedstrijd AS W
JOIN Team AS t1 ON t1.idTeam = w.Team1
JOIN Team AS t2 ON t2.idTeam = w.Team2
```